# Sqlite - how to iterate through Select Rows, then use in Insert

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to add on a column in which I calculate a count column. This count columns is at the User>Timestamp level, so if you start with an ordered table, you would go down from top to bottom, incrementing the count by 1, and setting it to 0 every time you get to a new user.

The way I thought I'd do this is using a Select statement to generate the ordered results, then iterate through each row and insert each row back into a new table, but also work out the count in the process.

In this case how do I use the row object returned by
for row in c.execute(sqlStr):

and easily re-insert all the columns in this row back into a new table but also add in a new column in the process?
I'm trying to avoid having to go through all the column names returned by row and construct a messy sql string (i.e. I only want to have to specify the new column and not type out all the existing column names).

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually think I figured it out, though not sure if it's the best way of doing it.
I've gone with doing something like:

```
for row in c.execute(sqlStr):
    a = str(row)[:-1] +', ' + newValue
```